# How do you set the application icon in golang?

Tags: go, icons

I've just created my first go application on Windows.

How do I give it an icon?

There doesn't seem to be any build flags to do this, and I know golang doesn't support resources.

Comment: I don't code on windows so I'm unsure but isn't the [relevant issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1552) closed following a new version of the tools adding support for .syso files ?

Comment: Not heard about that, can't seem to find much information about syso files either. Sounds like it might solve resource issues but not sure it will give the exe a nice icon.

Comment: @DenysSéguret syso files seem now (1.7.0-rc2) to be always included: https://github.com/golang/go/commit/0deb49f9c09d15bf0e4c5ec843bd374f9a377e97

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use a tool like [akavel/rsrc](https://github.com/akavel/rsrc) in order to generate a .syso file with specified resources embedded in `.rsrc` section, aimed for consumption by Go linker when building Win32 excecutables.

See as an example the [lxn/walk](https://github.com/lxn/walk#create-manifest-testmanifest) application, which embeds other metadata in its executable.

```
rsrc [-manifest FILE.exe.manifest] [-ico FILE.ico[,FILE2.ico...]] -o FILE.syso
```

`-ico=""`: comma-separated list of paths to .ico files to embed

---

This differs from embedding binary data into a go program.
For that, use [jteeuwen/go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata).

> To access asset data, we use the `Asset(string) []byte` function which is included in the generated output.

```
data := Asset("pub/style/foo.css")
if len(data) == 0 {
    // Asset was not found.
}

// use asset data
```

---

Update 2021: as noted in [John N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15345590/john-n)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66512832/6309), you can also use:

[**`github.com/tc-hib/go-winres`**](https://github.com/tc-hib/go-winres)

> A simple command line tool for embedding usual resources in Windows executables built with Go:
>
> - A manifest
> - An application icon
> - Version information (the Details tab in file properties)
> - Other icons and cursors

It can be used as a library too.

Comment: That works! I generated a syso file and added it to the root folder and it worked perfectly. What is the c file for?

Comment: @GordonTruslove it is for the Go code to access those resources to embed in the final exe.

Comment: You've lost me, I didn't add the c file and the icon still set. Are you saying it is so I can access files from within go? Like if I added File.dat, I could read this file at runtime using the c file?

Comment: @GordonTruslove no, it is for the go compilation process to access certain resources. apparently, it doesn't need it for ico resources.

Comment: If I try to add the file I created "res.c" the compiler throws an error: .\Res.c:1 not a function
.\Res.c:1 syntax error, last name: L

Comment: @GordonTruslove does it throw an error during "`go build`"?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure it out. I thing I'm using the rsrc tool wrong because the c file contains junk.

Comment: @GordonTruslove strange. As mentioned in https://github.com/akavel/rsrc/issues/4, those files are not to be compiled with regular C compiler, but with Go toolchain's one.

Comment: I'm trying to add a data file to see if that's any different, but rsrc just ignores it.

Comment: I'll keep trying. At least the icon works, which is awesome. It would be nice to figure out how to embed other files too. Like image resource files.

Comment: @GordonTruslove Oh, that would be https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata (for embedding images/text)

Comment: That works well, awesome again. Thanks. I'd give you a +1 but I don't know how.

Comment: @GordonTruslove You should have enough reputation points to upvote now

Answer (score 10):

The topic is long time, in fact `mingw` is only requirement, we don't need 3rd party dependency. In addition, resource file `*.rc` is mandatory for win32 executable application. At last, you can find the demo in [rc-demo](https://gitlab.com/gozoo/rc-demo)

1) Install mingw using Chocolatey: `choco install mingw`

2) Create `main.exe.manifest` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="x86"
    name="controls"
    type="win32"
/>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

3) Create `main.rc` file

```
100 ICON    "main.ico"
100 24      "main.exe.manifest"
101 RCDATA  "content.zip"
```

4) Build

In git-bash windows perform the following command:
`windres -o main-res.syso main.rc && go build -i`

Comment: >1) Install mingw using Chocolatey: choco install mingw
This requires 3rd party DevDependencies.

Answer (score 6):

This works well:

```
go install github.com/tc-hib/go-winres@latest
go-winres simply --icon youricon.png
go build
```

If your app has a GUI:
`go-winres simply --icon icon.png --manifest gui`

Comment: Confirmed as working 8/22/2023

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers worked for me. The only way I could get an ico embedded into a GO exe was with Resource Hacker.

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

1. Install and open Resource Hacker
2. Open compiled exe in Resource Hacker
3. Action > Add an image or other binary resource
4. Select ICO > Add Resource
5. Save and Close

You can also run it directly from the command line if you need to add it to your build scripts.

```
ResourceHacker -open main.exe -save output.exe -action addskip -res main.ico -mask ICONGROUP,MAIN,
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a github package [GoVersionInfo](https://github.com/josephspurrier/goversioninfo) by Joseph Spurrier:

> Microsoft Windows File Properties/Version Info and Icon Resource Generator for the Go Language
>
> Package creates a syso file which contains Microsoft Windows Version Information and an optional icon. When you run "go build", Go will embed the version information and an optional icon and an optional manifest in the executable. Go will automatically use the syso file if it's in the same directory as the main() function.

Answer (score 2):

This worked out for me

```
go get github.com/akavel/rsrc
rsrc -ico YOUR_ICON_FILE_NAME.ico
go build
```

Answer (score 1):

I delved into this issue for my requirements and the simple methods mentioned by [John N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15345590/john-n) and [Coconut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9552116/coconut) did not work as expected.

After more delving i figure out what was the problem and I share it so it might be useful for others.

- the syso file need to be part of a package used by the application.
- the syso file cant be placed in the root of the project when there is a `cmd/main.go` file used for the build.
- the syso file cant be placed in the main package of your application (i.e. placing the syso under `cmd` when building `cmd/main.go` file wont make it).

---

**couple examples that worked for me:**

#### flat project structure

```
...\test1
│   go.mod
│   main.go
│   rsrc.syso
```

where go.mod

```
module test1

go 1.19
```

and main.go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("test1")
}
```

then `go build` created `test1.exe` as expected

---

#### empty package

put syso file in a new folder package and create empty file with the package name, force import this package using `_`

```
...\test2
│   go.mod
│
├───cmd
│       main.go
│
└───rsrc
        rsrc.go
        rsrc.syso
```

where go.mod

```
module test2

go 1.19
```

rsrc.go

```
package rsrc
```

and main.go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        _ "test2/rsrc"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("test2")
}
```

then `go build -o test2.exe cmd\main.go` created `test2.exe` as expected

---

#### piggyback on existing package

place the syso file in a folder package that already used by the project app (**Note:** that different apps would have the same syso in case they use that package)

```
...\test3
│   go.mod
│
├───cmd
│       main.go
│
└───other
        other.go
        rsrc.syso
```

where go.mod

```
module test3

go 1.19
```

other.go

```
package other

func Foo() string {
        return "bar"
}
```

and main.go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "test3/other"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("test3")
        fmt.Println(other.Foo())
}
```

then `go build -o test3.exe cmd\main.go` created `test3.exe` as expected

---

#### using docker build flow

###### Dockerized build based on piggybacking on existing package

because, hey someone else probably needs this as well....
use the arch to set it to the proper ARCH if you have multi platform/architecture build flow

```docker
...
ARG TARGETARCH
ARG TARGETOS
RUN go install github.com/tc-hib/go-winres@latest
RUN go-winres simply --icon images/icon.png --out other/rsrc --arch ${TARGETARCH}
...
GOOS=${TARGETOS} GOARCH=${TARGETARCH} go build -o test3.exe cmd/main.go 
...
```

---

hope this helps anyone who got stuck

---

Answer (score 0):

you ant change a icon first think you know `setIcon() method` it only alow `byte[]` format so you first create image and convert into byte[]. so do following procedure.

```
// define icon path using os.Open()
iconFile, err := os.Open("/home/user/image/icon.png")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer iconFile.Close()

// png.Decode() to convert image path to image
img, err := png.Decode(iconFile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Then convert the image to byte[] format using bytes.Buffer
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
err1 := jpeg.Encode(buf, img, nil)
_ = err1

// save the converted byte[] to variable
img_buf := buf.Bytes()

// set the coverted byte[] icon using systray.SetTemplateIcon() method
systray.SetTemplateIcon(img_buf, img_buf)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: I think staytray places an icon at the system bar not at the binary

Comment: I think it's a bit off-topic, but thank you for sharing [systray](https://github.com/getlantern/systray) library!