# http.ListenAndServeTLS doesn't works on WIndows 8.1

Tags: windows, go, tls1.2

The following code works on Linux(docker golang:latest) but not with Windows 8.1:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    m := http.NewServeMux()
    m.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "ssl/localhost.cert", "ssl/localhost.key", m)
 }
```

On Windows, the server returns a 403 status code. No error on server side.

go version

```
go1.6 windows/amd64
```

Certificate is generated using http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: There is no error on the server side as you simply ignore the error returned by ListenAndServeTLS.

Comment: I'd expect some sort of firewall subsystem error preventing a process supposedly running in a lowered permissions mode (even if the user has administrative credentials) from binding to a privileged (below 1024) port. (Note that with the UAC turned on even administrators by default possess a security token with a lowered credentials and elevating them requires consent from the user in the form of a system-modal dialog.)

Comment: If my guess is a spot on, I'd try to combine [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25604878/720999) with [this](http://researchaholic.com/2010/07/15/how-to-set-an-exe-to-require-admin-authority-uac-on-launch/) for a start.

Comment: And by the way, the example in the [`net/http` documentation]() uses `log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())` to trap and display andy error possibly returned from `ListenAndServe()`. You *must* check errors in all the places they may arise.

Comment: @kostix On the port 8443, the servers works. Thanks !